# How to perform SQLite LIKE queries with wildcards not read as wildcards

Tags: sqlite

I'm running into a problem in SQLite when querying on text fields that happen to have the _ or % wildcard characters.

I have a table with a 'Name' field I want to query on. Two of my records have the value 'test' and 'te_t' in the 'Name' field I want to query on. If I run a query like below

```
"SELECT ALL * from Table WHERE Name LIKE 'te_t'"
```

This will return both the 'te_t' and 'test' records, because of '_' being read as a wildcard. How do I make it so that I only get the 'te_t' record from the above query?

I've done some research on this and read that I should be able to throw a backslash '\' character in front of the wildcard to get it to be read as a normal _ character instead of a wildcard. But when I try the query

```
"SELECT ALL * from Table WHERE Name LIKE 'te\_t'"
```

my query returns zero matches.

What am I doing wrong? Is this just not possible in SQLite?

Comment: Are you running this in a sql tool or as a string withing a programming language like PHP. If the latter, the language could be interpreting the escape character itself and by the time it gets to sqllite it's just a plain underscore instead of the backslash/underscore combination you want. If so, try \\_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, you can escape special characters in the LIKE pattern if you declare some escape character with ESCAPE:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Name LIKE 'te\_t' ESCAPE '\'
```

(see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like))